# Как программно вызвать событие для узла сцены (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx, события

Я создаю свое текстовое поле наследуя TextField:

```
public class MyTextField extends TextField{

    public MyTextField(){

        this.setOnKeyPressed(e->{

            //обработать нажатие "Enter"
            if(e.getCode().getName().equals("Enter")) {
                //do first command
            }
            //обработать другие клавиши
            else {
                //do second command
            }           
        });
    }

}
```

Дальше добавляю экземпляр этого класса и тестовую кнопку на сцену:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            //=====здесь суть=================================
            MyTextField myFld = new MyTextField();
            Button testBtn = new Button("Test");

            testBtn.setOnAction(e->{
                myFld.fireEvent( **какое событие?** );
            });
            //===============================================

            VBox root = new VBox(10, myFld, testBtn);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

В классе MyTextField описано, что должно происходить, если пользователь начнет ввод с клавиатуры. Ввод "Enter" обрабатывается отдельно.

Можно ли с помощью кнопки testBtn вызвать событие, что бы обьект myFld выполнил первую команду (do first command)?

Думаю что метод fireEvent(Event) вызывает событие для узла. Но как передать в этот метод событие нажатия клавиши "Enter" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Можно создать *событие* с нужными параметрами:

```
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, "", "", KeyCode.ENTER, false, false, false, false);

testBtn.setOnAction(e->{
    myFld.fireEvent(ke);
});
```

Конкретно для данного случая можно создать событие **ActionEvent** :

```
ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent();
testBtn.setOnAction(e->{
        myFld.fireEvent(ae);
    });
```